# Image viewer/ images for buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement simple image viewer, where you can choose from 2 pictures. I have one menubutton which offers these pictures. After choosing one of the images, the program creates 3 or 5 buttons. I would like to append to each of these buttons different images, so the first button would have one image and the second button would have another image and so on. I've created a function with for loop to create these buttons, but can't move on from that point. I can append one image to all of them, but can't do that one by one with different images.
Thanks for help

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk 

from functools import partial
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Halabala():
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.geometry("1100x700")

        self.lists_labels = []

        self.rbutton = tk.Menubutton(self.master, text = "Choose picture")
        self.picks2 = tk.Menu(self.rbutton)
        self.rbutton.config(menu=self.picks2)
        self.picks2.add_command(label = "Spider", command = partial(self.create_labels,3))
        self.picks2.add_command(label = "Sugar", command = partial(self.create_labels,5))
        self.rbutton.config(width = 30, bg = "white", bd = 5, relief = tk.RAISED)
        self.rbutton.place(x = 900, y = 30)

        self.master.mainloop()

    def create_labels(self, num):
        self.picture = Image.open("blue.gif")
        self.picture.thumbnail((130,130))
        self.tkim = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.picture)

        for label in self.lists_labels:
            label.destroy()
        self.lists_labels=[]

        for i in range(num):
            but = tk.Button(self.master, image = self.tkim)
            but.grid(row = i + 1, column = 0)
            self.lists_labels.append(but)


myapp = Halabala()
```

Comment: hint: you need a list of images to use for the different buttons. Currently, you only use one image. Then you can do like `but = tk.Button(self.master, image = self.list_tkims[i])`

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know how simple it actually is, but I have one more question. Is there a way to create a function, which will convert all the images to ImageTk and then somehow save them as "tkim_1", "tkim_2" and so on and not to convert each image one by one. Here's what I've tried to do: http://pastie.org/8624064

Comment: yes, you can use a loop to create them but save them in a list to use them afterwards. Now you are overwriting self.name in each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code relevant for your question:

```
class Halabala():
    def __init__(self):
        .............
        self.pictures = ["pavuk1", "pavuk2", "pavuk3"]

        self.lists_labels = []
        self.lists_images = []

        self.init_image_list()
        ............

    def init_image_list(self):
        for i in self.pictures:
            picture = Image.open(i)
            picture.thumbnail((130, 130))
            self.lists_images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(picture))

    def create_labels(self, num):
        for label in self.lists_labels:
            label.destroy()
        self.lists_labels=[]

        for i in range(num):
            but = tk.Button(self.master, image = self.lists_images[i])
            but.grid(row = i + 1, column = 0)
            self.lists_labels.append(but)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I now get access to original images(not as thumbnail), because I would like to create one main label and then update its image with images on the buttons. So when I click on the first button with image, that image will appear on the label, then click second button and that second image will appear and so on.

Comment: @Chilcone If the answer was useful for you vote it up. If you have a new, different question open a new post with that specific question. [Just questions...and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).